# Distinguish iPhone model with only a webpage?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

#### Problem

I am working at a company with a large base of field staff, all of whom were issued iPhones.  But those phones are of varying models, none earlier than an iPhone *4*.  I need a quick way of mapping out which person has which model iPhone, since that data isn't easily available.  I also cannot rely on them determining their own models as their are not all tech-savvy.

#### Proposed Solution

The only real way I can think to do this is to send a mass email with a link to a webpage that asks for their name and logs the relevant phone data.  I'm guessing that *user agent* and *screen dimensions* get me most of the way there, but I don't know enough about iPhones to be sure.  If they need to hold the phone in a particular orientation or scroll or whatever, I can provide instructions.

#### Questions

- Aside from user agent and screen dimensions (which I guess would more likely be viewport size), what else do I need to know about each iPhone to determine its model?
- Can I make those determinations entirely from the browser?
- Is there a way to distinguish an iPhone *4* from a *4s*, or a *5* from a *5s*?

*(Yes, yes, I know.  One should only ever "check for capabililty not version number."  But looking for capabilities is not my problem here.  I legitimately need to know which iPhone model each staffer has in their hands.  As far as I can tell, no one has fully addressed this problem on SO.)*

Comment: Not sure you could do this with browser only.  But what about a small app?

Comment: @box86rowh I don't have any experience yet with native apps, so it wouldn't be worth the effort for this particular use case.

Comment: OK.  That is probably the only way to do this.  Good luck though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have users take a photo with their phone and then send you the photo (or upload it using the webpage you create). By default, the EXIF metadata includes the phone model, so you'd just need to automate parsing the metadata and extracting the phone model.

Comment: I was never able to test this idea to confirm that it works (my job changed), but the underlying principle is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably tell between an iPhone 4 or iPhone 4s, as the UA will only contain information such as iOS version. You could tell between 4 and 5 by checking the screen size, but there's no way to reliably tell between 4 and 4s or 5 and 5s, at least with pure Javascript. With ObjC you could tell with `"hw.machine"`